# I want to make my app gather information from a website

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am kind of new at android developing and currently for my "first project" I made an app that has school scheudele stored for my school (only for my classmates). Now I want to expand this and make the app connect to the internet and take the scheudele that's stored on the website so that the app will be usable by the whole school.

This is link to my whole school scheudele: http://www.s-stps.tb.edus.si/dijaki/urniki.html

It's in my native language so you won't really understand anything but as you can see there are 3 different drop down menus over the table and this is what I want my app to have. A dropdown menu where you will be able to choose which class you're in, then app will connect to the internet and take that class's scheudele and show it, maybe even download it so that further internet connection isn't neccessary.

I know I'm asking a lot and for someone who doesn't know much about android programming this will be pretty hard to make but I have 2 months of holidays to do this so I'll give it a try. I'd be very thankful for some useful pointers, advice on how to start doing this.

Comment: are you able to 'download' the schedule as xml, json or ical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the page and parse the html content. Downloading the page should be easy, give you an example:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;

String url = "http://www.whatever.com";
String html = "";

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
request = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    html = out.toString();
}
```

This cannot be run on the main thread, so you need to run it with asynctask or a runnable.
For parsing you can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). The problem here is not using JSoup itself because it's quite easy, but instead decifrate the document structure.
Here helloworld with JSoup:

```
String html = "<html><head></head><body><p>asdasd1</p><p>asdasd2</p></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements p = doc.select("p");

for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++){
    Log.i("p",p.get(i).text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! Do I need to add any permissions for this? Such as internet connection permission?

Comment: oh yes! sorry forgot to mention, I'm looking for a jsoup example ^^

Comment: Awesome, I don't understand everything yet but with practice comes knowledge :P Thank you :)

Comment: I'm sure you will, parsing data from website is very funny, you can download a whole database from a website and use it for your purpose (this is not always legal uh) ^^ if you have more doubt feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

If you can download the schedule in json take a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial. If you can download it in xml, take a look at this [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)